# Pointing domain to my IP an port

Tags: apache, httpd

I have a server with ip

> 55.335.32.56:4000

but want to use my domain

> user.example.com

I am trying to do this with apache via httpd:vhost.conf

> Listen 4000
>
> <VirtualHost 55.335.32.56:4000>
>
> ServerName user.example.com
>
> ServerAlias [www.user.example.com](http://www.user.example.com)

Hope someone can show my the correct way.

Comment: So what is the problem and what are you trying to achieve? Do you want your website to be found under `http(s)://user.example.com:4000`? But then you should also adapt the DNS configuration for your domain name: nameservers, IP addresses (IPv4 and possibly IPv6 where appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are asking is not possible.

You can use https://user.example.com:4000 but not https://user.example.com

This is because DNS does not provide a way to advise what port a website is on.  It is assumed that HTTP is on port 80, HTTPS is on 443, and if this is not the case the port needs to be stated explicitly (with :portno after the domain name/IP).

For the sake of clarity, there are mechanisms in DNS which allow a protocol to be advised of the port (SRV records), but these are not supported by the HTTP/HTTPS protocols.

Comment: A common work around is to use a reverse proxy on port 80 / 443 which fetches the content from another port on the same or a different host.

Comment: "what you are asking is not possible." Yet or now. It is possible with DNS `SVCB`/`HTTPS` records because like `SRV` they allow to specify a port, hence allow to do HTTPS on other ports than 443, without mentioning it in the URL. Not 100% standard ratified yet or used everywhere, but since 2020 both CloudFlare, Apple, Google, etc. started to use those records (publishing or fetching them in browsers). There would be no harm to start using them even if all clients are not aware of them yet.

Comment: Make a virtual host at https://user.example.com that return a redirect to https://user.example.com:4000